# Не выводятся большие изображения в base64

Tags: php, html, база-данных, base64

Здравствуйте. Установил себе на сайт графический редактор, и когда вставляю изображение и сохраняю, все данные кодируются в base64 и отправляются в БД. Проблема в том, чтобы вывести потом изображения. Текст выводит, а изображения не все. Заметил, что не выводит только большие изображения. В чем может быть проблема?

Вот код вывода:

```
strip_tags(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), '<img><a><b><i><u><ul><li><ol><span><div><br><p>')
```

Переменная `$text` содержит текст и изображения

Возможно стоит какой то лимит данных которые передаются? Вывожу я все это дело с помощью Ajax.

Comment: Может поле в базе где храните строку например varchar(250) и оно обрезается ? ) Или в переменной text точно вся информация есть ?

Comment: @Moonvvell, в бд тип поля стоит не varchar а text, в переменной точно все есть, через бд я вижу что там.

Comment: @Moonvvell, может быть такое, что дело в хостинге? А то находил что то о ModSecurity

Comment: А если вывести $text как текст он целиком и заканчивается на = или ==?

Comment: @Abmin, в mysql text это всего-лишь 65к байт!!!

Comment: Попробуйте `LONGTEXT` вместо `TEXT`. Или еще лучше храните картинки в файлах!

Comment: @Crantisz, я бы хранил в файлах если бы знал как. Это получается визуальный редактор summernote, и я просто беру из него html код. Мне бы подошел такой вариант как на этом сайте при загрузке изображений, с помощью стороннего сервиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные необходимо передавать в формате form-data.И  хранить на сервере не в БД.

Comment: Спасибо. Так и сделал. Теперь использую сервис Imgur (как на этом сайте). Но так как у меня есть ssl сертификат а у imgur его нету, то при загрузке изображения у меня появляется восклицательный знак вместо зеленого замка.

Comment: а ошибка какая-то есть. Я правильно понял вы аяксом загружаете картинку или вы iframe вставили на сайт?

Comment: я Аяксом делал. Уже все нормально, я просто регуляркой заменяю http на https

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно стоит какой то лимит данных которые передаются?

Именно так. "изображения в base64" не что иное как [data: URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397). А URL имеет [ограниченную длину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9E.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.8B) и зависит от юзерагента и [хопов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Кроме того подобное кодирование увеличивает объём данных. В бинарном виде картинка весит гораздо меньше. Поэтому просто нет смысла (и даже вредно) кодировать большие данные.

Comment: То есть лучше всего просто указывать ссылку на изображение в БД?

Comment: Изображение в БД? Не знаю... Как по мне - изображения нужно хранить физ. файпам. И вставлять так же. Но может и есть задачи где БД будет предпочтительно, но я таких не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

> Заметил, что не выводит только большие изображения. В чем может быть проблема?

В больших изображениях больше вероятность, что `strip_tags` что-то испортит. Вероятно, если отдать такую картинку в `strip_tags`, то возвращённая строка будет отличаться от оригинальной.

PS: http://ithappens.me/story/421

Comment: Без `strip_tags` так же изображений нету, так что думаю проблема все таки в длинне.